# Indy IMAP cuts off message at dot

Tags: delphi, imap, indy

I am receiving emails from an Exchange server using the Indy TIdIMAP4 component's `UIDRetrieve()` function under Delphi XE with the Indy components version 10.5.7.

This normally works fine, though sometimes the message is cut off at a dot followed by a line break. This happens when the dot is exactly at column 76.

Example:
I call `IMAPConnection.UIDRetrieve(1, Email);` with email 1 having the following body:

```
The message's text will be cut off at the dot at column 76, so exactly here.
This text won't be accessible via TIdMessage.
```

What I then receive when I call `Email.Body.Text` is this:

```
The message's text will be cut off at the dot at column 76, so exactly here
```

So the second sentence is not available in `Email`.
When I access the message body via telnet it looks like this:

```
The message's text will be cut off at the dot at column 76, so exactly here=
.
This text won't be accessible via TIdMessage.
```

This also happens when I have a multipart message and I access the message part body via `TIdText(MsgPart).Body.Text`. In this case also any message attachments are not retrieved.

Is there any property I have to set or function I have to call on my IMAP connection or the message object to avoid this?

Sebastian

Comment: Bizarre. I don't know much about Indy, so no answer, but I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: A period on a line by itself is what signifies the end of a message in SMTP — perhaps IMAP, too? If so, then in looks to me like the server is mis-encoding the message before it sends it to your client.

Comment: No, imap uses a size prefix, not dots

Comment: IMAP does not use SMTP dot transparency, but Indy's implementation of IMAP does. This was a bug in older versions, and was finally addressed not too long ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version of Indy is outdated.  You need to upgrade.  This issue was already addressed in `TIdIMAP4` back in December 2012 in SVN rev 4883.  The current version in Indy's SVN is 10.6.0 rev 5022.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That was also my first thought. So I already tried to install 10.6.0 (i.e. actually the current version on SVN) a while ago. Though I wasn't successful yet. Even by removing all old code, packages, etc. referencing to Indy as described in the [Indy installation instructions](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.de.aspx) (at least I couldn't find any other related things) and recompiling everything I had version 10.5.7 after that again for some reason. But I'll try again.

Comment: I assure you, 10.5.7 is not the current SVN version. If you are still seeing 10.5.7 show up after installing the SVN version, then you still have old files installed that the IDE/compiler is finding first instead of finding the newer files.

Comment: You were right. Seems like I missed to delete some old DCU files before. Now I have 10.6.0 and it is finally working as expected. Thanks again!

Comment: I just realized that you were also the one that made that fix. So I have to double-thank you! :-)